# Show current time moving (floating)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

my question is as i wrote in the title

"Show current time moving animated"

in php we do:

```
<? echo date("H:I:S"); ?>
```

to show current time (hour:minute:second)

so i want  a way to make it refreshed each second which mean it start floating

hope you understand what im talking about and thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that you need php for that, usually js is enough:

```js
function t() {
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = new Date();
}
t();
window.setInterval(t, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: thank you thats useful but how can i print out in format H:I:S

Comment: @script0r Date object has several methods, so you can get hours/minutes/seconds

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a simple but configurable clock from W3schools that would allow you to style it how you like:

```js
function startTime() {

    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    h = h > 12 ? h - 12 : h;
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>
```

If you want to use 24 hour time, just remove the line `h = h > 12 ? h - 12 : h;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `setInterval`:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  // get time
  // update time
}, 1000)
```

This pseudo code will run every 1 second. I recommend getting the time every pass, because it'll take a little longer than a second (JavaScript is like that), and you'll get out of sync.
I can't write demo code without knowing how you're going to use this, but I hope this helps some.