# Js ,how to make the time I rounded up can follow what's on my pc

Tags: javascript

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOTfk.jpg)

I want the timer script that I made to follow the time on my pc, where is the wrong part of the code, please correct the wrong part of the code, thank you

```
   enter code here

   let countdown = new Date (new Date().getHours()
   + 1,0,1 );
   let $hours = document.getElementById('hours');
   let $minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
   let $seconds =document.getElementById('seconds')


   setInterval(function() {
   var now = new Date();
   var timeleft = (countdown , now) / 1000;
   updateclock(timeleft);
   
   
   },1000);
```

```
      function updateclock(remainingTime){
      let hours = Math.floor(remainingTime / 3600) %
      24;
      remainingTime -= hours * 3600;
      let minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime / 60) %
      60;
      remainingTime -= minutes * 60
      let seconds = Math.floor(remainingTime % 60);
```

```
 $hours.innerHTML = Number(hours);
      $minutes.innerHTML = Number(minutes);
      $seconds.innerHTML = Number(seconds);
    }

    function Number (Number) {
        return Number < 10 ? + Number : Number;
    }
```

Comment: `(countdown , now)` what do you want to achieve by this? subtract one from another?

Comment: no I don't want to reduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subtracting one value from another does not reduce original variables, unless you explicitly assign result to one of them

anyway, the main problem was `(countdown , now)` statement, which should be actually: `(countdown.valueOf() - now.valueOf())`

```js
let countdown = new Date ();
countdown.setHours(countdown.getHours()+1);
let $hours = document.getElementById('hours');
let $minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
let $seconds =document.getElementById('seconds')

setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date();
  var timeleft = (countdown.valueOf() - now.valueOf()) / 1000;
  updateclock(timeleft);
},1000);
      
function updateclock(remainingTime){
  remainingTime = parseInt(remainingTime, 10);
  let seconds = remainingTime % 60;
  remainingTime = Math.floor(remainingTime / 60);
  let minutes = remainingTime % 60;
  remainingTime = Math.floor(remainingTime / 60);
  let hours = remainingTime;
 
  $hours.innerHTML = Number(hours);
  $minutes.innerHTML = Number(minutes);
  $seconds.innerHTML = Number(seconds);
}

function Number (number) {
  return (number >=0 && number < 10) ? ("0" + number) : number;
}
```

```html
<span id="hours"></span> : <span id="minutes"></span> : <span id="seconds"></span>
```

Comment: how to increase the time and not decrease it?

Comment: @Kiki what do you mean? do you want to display current time or time elapsed since start of the script?

Comment: current time, following the time on my pc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35807424/2864275